# GLEW 1.9.0 builds a 64-bit .so even with m32 argument?

Tags: shared-libraries, 32bit-64bit, cross-compiling, glew

I've been trying to compile a 32-bit shared library of GLEW-1.9.0 under a 64-bit RedHat 4 machine, but it seems no matter what I try, the shared library it produces is 64-bit (this is determined using "file libGLEW*" in the output directory).

It seems GLEW has its own system for detecting the architecture. Ultimately, this comes down to "shell uname -m", which I've attempted to change using "setarch i386". The output of "uname -m" after that call is "i686", which isn't i386, but should still be 32-bit.

I've been setting CFLAGS.EXTRA before my 32-bit build to "-m32 -Wl,-rpath,$(APPDIR32)/lib -fPIC", where $(APPDIR32) is the directory I'm outputting to, as well as where I'm linking libraries from. This worked just fine for my 64-bit build (except with the '32's in the string replaced with '64's).

I've been using GLEW's Makefile as follows (after setting the variables mentioned above, among other less relevant ones): "make -f Makefile all"

Setting LDFLAGS to -m32 or melf_i386 has no effect on the format of the output file, which always ends up in ELF_64 (not ELF_32). The libraries being linked are all 32-bit, and that's one of the reasons it complains, as a describe below.

During the build I get repeated warnings like the following...

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: i386 architecture of input file `tmp/linux/default/shared/glew.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
```

One question: Is i686 a 32-bit architecture? The wikipedia page is unclear on this. I found a point in that page where it says some i686 processors have support for 64-bit instruction sets.

Another question: I haven't been able to find any useful information on building 32-bit shared libraries for GLEW in a 64-bit environment. Can you give me any pointers?

And the ultimate question: Can you see where I'm going wrong, or do you know about an additional action I need to take to get this building a 32-bit shared library?

In response to request for information about the exact command line and its output for the warning mentioned above, it is as follows...

```
cc -shared -Wl,-soname=libGLEW.so.1.9 -o lib/libGLEW.so.1.9.0 tmp/linux/default/shared/glew.o -L/usr/X11R6/lib -L/usr/lib -lXmu -lXi -lGL -lXext -lX11 
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libXmu.so when searching for -lXmu
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libXi.so when searching for -lXi
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libGL.so when searching for -lGL
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libXext.so when searching for -lXext
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libX11.so when searching for -lX11
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libc.so when searching for -lc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libc.a when searching for -lc
/usr/bin/ld: warning: i386 architecture of input file `tmp/linux/default/shared/glew.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
```

Here's my makefile, in case you get really excited and want more material. This makefile will work just fine if you put it in the same directory as GLEW-1.9.0's Makefile (that is until you try configure32). Just make sure to set TOPDIR. Use 'make -f  clean', 'make -f  configure32', 'make -f  all', 'make -f  install'.

```
APPLICATION = glew
VERSION = 1.9.0
FULLAPPLICATION = $(APPLICATION)-$(VERSION)

TOPDIR = /home/<username>/dev/project/third-party

APPDIRROOT  = $(TOPDIR)/apps-miles

ARCH=$(shell uname | sed -e 's/-//g')
SHELL = /bin/csh

MACHTYPE32= i386
APPDIR32                = $(APPDIRROOT)/$(ARCH)_$(MACHTYPE32)

MACHTYPE64= x86_64
APPDIR64                = $(APPDIRROOT)/$(ARCH)_$(MACHTYPE64)

#
#   Linux
#

ifeq ($(ARCH), Linux)
CC = gcc 
CXX = g++
CFLAGS.EXTRA32 += -m32 -Wl,-rpath,$(APPDIR32)/lib -fPIC
CFLAGS.EXTRA64 += -m64 -Wl,-rpath,$(APPDIR64)/lib -fPIC
PATH = /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
endif

#
# Darwin
#

ifeq ($(ARCH), Darwin)
CC = gcc 
CXX = g++
CFLAGS.EXTRA32 += -m32 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -fPIC
CFLAGS.EXTRA64 += -m64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -fPIC
PATH = /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
endif


V_M_EXIST = $(shell test -e CONFIG.mk && echo 1)
ifeq ($(V_M_EXIST), 1)
include CONFIG.mk
endif


ECHO = echo

all::
    make -f Makefile all

configure32::
    @-/bin/rm CONFIG.mk; touch CONFIG.mk
    @echo "GLEW_DEST = $(APPDIR32)" >> CONFIG.mk
    @echo "export GLEW_DEST" >> CONFIG.mk
    @echo "LIBDIR = $(APPDIR32)/lib" >> CONFIG.mk
    @echo "export LIBDIR" >> CONFIG.mk
    @echo "CFLAGS.EXTRA = $(CFLAGS.EXTRA32)" >> CONFIG.mk
    @echo "export CFLAGS.EXTRA" >> CONFIG.mk


configure64::
    @-/bin/rm VAPOR.mk; touch CONFIG.mk
    @echo "GLEW_DEST = $(APPDIR64)" >> CONFIG.mk
    @echo "export GLEW_DEST" >> CONFIG.mk
    @echo "LIBDIR = $(APPDIR64)/lib" >> CONFIG.mk
    @echo "export LIBDIR" >> CONFIG.mk
    @echo "CFLAGS.EXTRA = $(CFLAGS.EXTRA64)" >> CONFIG.mk
    @echo "export CFLAGS.EXTRA" >> CONFIG.mk

install::
    make -f Makefile install

clean::
    make -f Makefile clean

frog:: 
    @$(ECHO) APPDIR = $(APPDIR32)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** updated to reflect seemingly working workaround

### First approach

As linking 32-bit code with 64-bit libs will not work on first sight the only problem seemed to be the following snippet of `config/Makefile.linux` starting on line 5:

```
M_ARCH ?= $(shell uname -m)
ifeq (x86_64,${M_ARCH})
LDFLAGS.EXTRA = -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -L/usr/lib64
LIBDIR = $(GLEW_DEST)/lib64
else
LDFLAGS.EXTRA = -L/usr/X11R6/lib -L/usr/lib
LIBDIR = $(GLEW_DEST)/lib
endif
```

hardcoding the library search path to 64-bit libraries.

### Second sight

As a first attempt trying something like:

```
make  LDFLAGS=-m32 M_ARCH=anything_but_not_x86_64
```

still failed it turned out that in addition disregarding common conventions `LDFLAGS` will not be passed to the linker in the `Makefile` going with rules like the one on line 108:

```
lib/$(LIB.SHARED): $(LIB.SOBJS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS.SO) -o $@ $^ $(LIB.LDFLAGS) $(LIB.LIBS)
```

With LDFLAGS.whatever hardcoded to required switches.

### Suggested workaround

While any of the workarounds like:

- `make LDFLAGS.SO="-L/usr/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib -m32"`

should work the most easy one to type seems to be the following one:

- `make LD="gcc -m32"`

smuggling the `-m32` switch into the `LD` macro.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, I've been working in a shell where uname -m returns i686, which is because I used setarch i386... Actually, I see what you mean. The shell it starts to check uname -m will not be a shell where setarch has been used. I'll try adjusting that line and get back to you. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: I don't know how this is happening, but I'm still getting a 64-bit .so output, even after using various methods to set M_ARCH. I've also manually edited Makefile.linux, but to no avail. I'm even getting exactly the same warnings.

Comment: As `ld` is complaining it still looks like a problem with the linked libs. Probably you should post the whole command line that raises the given error. Just to make sure the sources got correctly compiled. `readelf -h glew.o` should report something like `Class: ELF32` and `Machine: Intel 80386`
`

Comment: I posted the command line. Note that it is not an error, just a warning, and the output library is changed to 64-bit (it's a successful build that is works perfectly as a 64-bit .so). Also, I checked the output of that readelf line, and it reads ELF32 and Intel 80386.

Comment: Seems `-m32` got lost on the way: `cc -shared -Wl,-soname=libGLEW.so.1.9 -o lib/libGLEW.so.1.9.0 tmp/linux/default/shared/glew.o -L/usr/X11R6/lib -L/usr/lib -lXmu -lXi -lGL -lXext -lX11`. I'm quite sure that's your problem.

Comment: Can you see a way for me to force it to include the -m32 argument at all costs?

Comment: A quick and dirty hack would be to smuggle it in in LD with `make LD="gcc -m32"`.

Comment: YES!!!! THANKS!!!! Very nice! Could you adjust your answer to that effect? (That worked)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be too easy to find a usable variable if there is any. Unfortunately the documentation (if any) doesn't seem to give any advice here. `Unix: make Windows: ...` in `README.txt` is the only build instruction I found.

Comment: As suggested I'll edit the post above - just in case another one gets stuck in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

Things may have changed with glew since the other answer was useful.  I have had better luck with

```
make -j LDFLAGS.SO=-m32 LDFLAGS.DYNAMIC=-m32 CFLAGS=-m32
```

If you're building both 32bit and 64bit libraries, don't forget to `make clean` in between building both.